# Lines Drawn on HTML Canvas Not Appearing with Touch Events

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touch

I've got a canvas element used for practicing drawing in a panel on my page, and I've managed to disable the scroll event when people touch inside it.  I refigured the code to create a separate set of actions for handling touch events, but the lines aren't showing up, even though I've tagged the events in the console and the touches are being registered properly.

What am I missing?

### HTML

```
<canvas class="js-paint paint-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

### CSS

```
canvas {
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent scrolling when trying to use the canvas in touch mode */
}

.paint-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### JS

```
const paintCanvas = document.querySelector( '.js-paint' );
const context = paintCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.strokeStyle = '#222222'; // Hex code with preceding #
context.lineWidth = 10; // Integer value

const lineWidthRange = document.querySelector( '.js-line-range' );
const lineWidthLabel = document.querySelector( '.js-range-value' );

let x = 0, y = 0;

// Drawing with mouse
let isMouseDown = false;

const stopDrawing = () => { isMouseDown = false; }

const startDrawing = event => {
  isMouseDown = true;
  [x, y] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
}

const drawLine = event => {
  if ( isMouseDown ) {
    const newX = event.offsetX;
    const newY = event.offsetY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo( x, y );
    context.lineTo( newX, newY );
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mousedown', startDrawing );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', drawLine );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stopDrawing );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mouseout', stopDrawing );

// For tablets
let isTouchDown = false;

const stopDrawingTouch = () => {
  isTouchDown = false;
}
const startDrawingTouch = event => {
  isTouchDown = true;
  [x, y] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
}
const drawLineTouch = event => {
  if ( isTouchDown ) {
    const newX = event.offsetX;
    const newY = event.offsetY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo( x, y );
    context.lineTo( newX, newY );
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchstart', startDrawingTouch );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchmove', drawLineTouch );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchend', stopDrawingTouch );
    // Not sure if there's a touch equivalent to 'mouseout'; OK with skipping it for now in the name of simplicity
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer while writing the question, so in the interest of not pulling a DenverCoder9 I figured I'd best do a quick write-up for the community.

Getting started, here's a fiddle of the working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaji_Sensei/hvusjx9L/10/

So the first part of the issue is that, being a touch event, we needed to actually capture the touch itself to get its coordinates.  To do that, calls to `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` become calls to `event.touches[0].screenX` and `event.touches[0].screenY` instead.

In and of itself that's not sufficient, however, because we still need the offset information so that the coordinates stay within the canvas.  In order to do this we use `jQuery('.js-paint').offset().left` and `jQuery('.js-paint').offset().top` to get those distances.

For X we simply subtracted the offset from `event.touches[0].screenX` to land in the right place.

Y was a bit more complicated and took some testing.  The tests are noted in the fiddle comments, but the short answer is that for some reason we need to divide the Y offset in half before subtracting it from `event.touches[0].screenY` in order to place the point right under where the touch occurs.

### HTML

```
<canvas class="js-paint paint-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

### CSS

```
canvas {
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent scrolling when trying to use the canvas in touch mode */
}

.paint-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### JS

```
const paintCanvas = document.querySelector( '.js-paint' );
const context = paintCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.strokeStyle = '#222222'; // Hex code with preceding #
context.lineWidth = 10; // Integer value

const lineWidthRange = document.querySelector( '.js-line-range' );
const lineWidthLabel = document.querySelector( '.js-range-value' );

let x = 0, y = 0;

// Drawing with mouse
let isMouseDown = false;

const stopDrawing = () => { isMouseDown = false; }

const startDrawing = event => {
  isMouseDown = true;
  [x, y] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
}

const drawLine = event => {
  if ( isMouseDown ) {
    const newX = event.offsetX;
    const newY = event.offsetY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo( x, y );
    context.lineTo( newX, newY );
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mousedown', startDrawing );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', drawLine );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stopDrawing );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'mouseout', stopDrawing );

// For tablets
let isTouchDown = false;
let touchXOffset = jQuery('.js-paint').offset().left;
let touchYOffset = jQuery('.js-paint').offset().top / 2;
// Subtracting the offset isn't working
// Offset to 0 isn't working
// Add offset instead of dividing isn't working
// TEST: Offset divided by 2 <-- WORKS!

const stopDrawingTouch = () => {
  isTouchDown = false;
}
const startDrawingTouch = event => {
  isTouchDown = true;
  console.log(event.touches[0]);
  [x, y] = [(event.touches[0].screenX - touchXOffset), (event.touches[0].screenY - touchYOffset)];

  console.log('X: ' + event.touches[0].screenX + ' offset by ' + touchXOffset);
  console.log('Y: ' + event.touches[0].screenY + ' offset by ' + touchYOffset);
}
const drawLineTouch = event => {
  if ( isTouchDown ) {
    const newX = event.touches[0].screenX - touchXOffset;
    const newY = event.touches[0].screenY - touchYOffset;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo( x, y );
    context.lineTo( newX, newY );
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchstart', startDrawingTouch );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchmove', drawLineTouch );
paintCanvas.addEventListener( 'touchend', stopDrawingTouch );
    // Not sure if there's a touch equivalent to 'mouseout'; OK with skipping it for now in the name of simplicity
```

Comment: @ggorlen Gotcha!  Haven't posted in a while, didn't realize the practice had changed.  Editing code in now.